# ELF sym global var offset is not right

Tags: elf

[image]

[image]

I want to parse the ELF format file, get the address of the sym table by parsing the ELF file, and then find the address of the global variable dumper_elf_data.

I saw it in 010editor. The address of the variable dumper_elf_data is F004, but the actual real address is E004. , Why not F004,

I want to parse ELF to get this E004 address, what should I do,

it seems that the actual address is to be subtracted from 0x1000,

but how do I get the value to be subtracted (0x1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the value to be subtracted (0x1000)

It's the difference between `.p_vaddr == 0xEB20` and `.p_offset == 0xDB20`.